# angular ui-router: how do I reload a state when a path parameter changes but not reload when a query parameter changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

For example, I want this change in navigation to reload the state:

- `#/detail/1`
- `#/detail/2`

But I do not want this navigation to reload the state:

- `#/detail/1?search=blah`
- `#/detail/1?search=huzzah`

According to the ui-router documentation, setting `reloadOnSearch: false` should accomplish this, but try the plunk below. When `reloadOnSearch === false`, changing the path parameter doesn't reload the state even though the documentation says it should.

Plunkr: http://run.plnkr.co/ZPy9uabYlkMilwdS/#/param

Comment: DId you ever find a solution to do what you stated above? I'm needing the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in UI-Router that was fixed in release 0.2.15:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases

Upgrading to the latest will fix the issue

Answer (score 35):

I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5sN7bHxt5e0FIndZN8Im?p=preview), demonstrating that `ui-router` feature `reloadOnSearch` is working as documented [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#reloadonsearch-v025):

> #### reloadOnSearch:
>
> Boolean *(default true)*. If false will not retrigger **the same state** just because a **search/query parameter** has changed. Useful for when you'd like to modify $location.search() without triggering a reload.

So, what this says, that if we do have state like this

```
.state('index.detail', {
      url: '/detail/:id',
      reloadOnSearch : false,
      ...
    })
```

navigating to the

- `ui-sref="index.detail({id:1})"`

will load this state, while navigating to

- `ui-sref="index.detail({id:any-other-id})"`

will do nothing. But! If we would introduce new *(e.g. sibling)* state defined like this:

```
.state('index.other', {
      url: '/other/:id',
      reloadOnSearch : false,
      ...
    })
```

navigating to below sequence will always re-trigger state reload, **not because the param change, but because the state change**

1. `<a href="#/index/detail/1" ...`
2. `<a href="#/index/other/1"  ... // will relaod`
3. `<a href="#/index/detail/2" ... // because the state`
4. `<a href="#/index/other/2"  ... // is changing`

See that all in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5sN7bHxt5e0FIndZN8Im?p=preview)...

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question. "If false will not retrigger the same state just because a *search/query parameter* has changed." "search/query parameter" refers to $location.search(), i.e. everything after the question mark. I want to be able to change what's before the question mark and reload the state.

Comment: This is missunderstanding of the terms. 1) search/query parameters are parts of the url mapped as params (e.g. **stateName/paramValue/stateName?param1=value1&param2=value2**). Parts mapped as state-name identificators are the rest. So what is the *reloadOnSearch = false* about? do not trigger state reload, if params parts of the url are changed. But if the state itself is changed... it will reidrect. Is it a bit more clear?

Comment: From perspective of the `ui-router`, url represents unique state definition. It could be one or many/nested states with many params. Some could be even in a format of a https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters - query params. But at the end, this url is converted into 1) states and 2) params. Nothing more. And reloadOnSearch=false means: any param of current state has changed == do not reload. That exactly is what the docum. says, and that's what my plunker shows 1:1. But I just tried to explain, do not get me wrong... I accept that you see that differently..

Comment: @MattYork in your OP you are changing the parts after the hash, and have reloadOnSearch set to false - which is designed to ignore changes in the parts after the hash. The issue is very simple to understand. The documentation may be ambiguous, but RadimKöhler is simply stating true facts about how it works.

Comment: seems like quite a hack to introduce a sibling state, makes for messy URLs for your application. Is it possible to do it the way @MattYork was intending?

Comment: @JonHarding Not sure if there is answer ... other than this. *Just my little personal note - I am using UI-Router pretty long time, and I was able to successfully cover all business needs with implementation as is (mostly 0.2.15 version)*

Comment: @RadimKöhler the idea of sibling routes is ridiculous especially if it's to view the exact same information. Query string and $stateParams should be treated differently in my opinion

Comment: @RadimKöhler this is, in fact, a bug in UI-Router. Acknowledged here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1191. The "fix" talked about in the bug report did not work

Your workaround requires having two different urls for the state, but that's not acceptable for us.

We also have used ui-router for a long time. We have very specific url requirements, and we've found UI-Router to be buggy and inflexible. Doing anything that's not by-the-book requires hacks (we were literally encouraged by the maintainers to change the source to get the functionality we need).

Comment: @JoshRibakoff there's two different types of url parameters: path and search (aka query). reloadOnSearch is intended to only apply to search parameters, not path parameters. See this issue: github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1191

Comment: @MattYork, It is a shame that you did not your solution.. without hacking. Check this latest branch... https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/feature-1.0#feature-10-branch, maybe the future 1.0 could satisfy your needs